# Haskell instance multiple context

Tags: haskell, instance

```
class Countable a where
  count :: [a]
```

Class Countable is a class that should implement the method `count`, which returns a list all possible values of `a` without duplicate. For example if `a` is `Bool`, then `count` should be `[True, False]`.

Lets say we want to have an instance `Countable (Maybe a)` assuming `a` is already `Countable`, then we can just implement count accordingly.

```
instance Countable a => Countable (Maybe a) 
   count = map Just countable ++ [Nothing]
```

But what if we want an instance which has multiple contexts? How can we access the function `count` of `a` and `b`? `count` doesn't take any parameter so how should haskell find out if a or b is meant?
Like

```
instance (Countable a, Countable b) => Countable (a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can write this instance like so:

```hs
instance (Countable a, Countable b) => Countable (a, b)
    count = [ (x, y) | x <- count, y <- count ]
```

So, outer `count` has type `[(a, b)]`, and inner `count`s have types `[a]` and `[b]` accordingly.

Comment: Ahh ok Thanks. But I wonder how would you do that if ```instance (Countable a, Countable b) => Countable (Either a b) where ```. How did Haskell find out which count belongs to a or b?

Comment: @trollinator It's another question) But you can define this as `map Left count ++ map Right count`

Comment: @trollinator About "How did Haskell find out which count belongs to a or b?" - It's just type checking.